# Decoding nested JSON into structure that adopts Decodable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have the following JSON that I want to decode:

```
{
    "id":5,
    "items_received":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Doug"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use structures like:

```
struct Delivery: Equatable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let items: [Item]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case items = "items_received"
    }
}

struct Item: Equatable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

and call:

```
{ try self.jsonDecoder.decode(Delivery.self, from: value) }
```

and get:

> FAILURE: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "items_received",
>   intValue: nil)

Comment: Basically this code is correct and should work. However this error occurs if you specify the key decoding strategy `.convertFromSnakeCase`. Don't do that in this case or rename `items` to `itemsReceived` and delete the CodingKeys.

Comment: I would suggest you to use SwiftyJson library.    let responseJSON : JSON = JSON(result!)  after API response would make JSON parsing so much easier.

Comment: @S.S.D I disagree. `Codable` is much easier to use and it's much less code to write and you get **real** objects rather than generic arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: @vadian I will accept your comment as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Agree with @vadian

Comment: @bhartsb Keeping `convertFromSnakeCase` you can declare the enum case `case items = "itemsReceived"`. That works, too

Comment: @vadian that makes sense :)